# Keep box of selected option open in html/css dropdown menu without use JS

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie in html and css and I have to build a dropdown menu. I've found many examples in [here](http://www.smashingapps.com/2013/02/18/48-free-dropdown-menu-in-html5-and-css3.html).

As I can't use JS, I would like to, whenever in a subpage, have the options be highlighted and keep the box open. So far, I can highlight the options easily but the block keep closing (and don't show up open when open the page).

The code is in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/og5z5mpj/) and the idea is to keep the submenu inside Menu 3 open (as if you were in Link 4 page).

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this? Cheers!

Code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"> Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="subactive" tabindex="1">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a style="background:#d4d5d8;" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    border:3px solid #3e4547;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;
    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color:#d4d5d8;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}

#nav a.sub:focus {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}

#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}

#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display:block;
}

#nav a.sub:active {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top:0;
}

#nav a.subactive {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
```

The key part here seem to be with this class I created but not sure what put inside.

```
#nav a.subactive {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/r5c6kez0/) the boring way to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

Normally I find adding things like

```
#nav ul ul{
display: block !important;
}
```

or

```
div.container {
height: auto !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

would work, however it would appear that because focus is lost, it closes. I did have luck with the div.container but it only remained open for a short period longer than normal before closing again. Hopefully this helps if even just a tad.

!important is used to over-ride the inline styles that are applied with js so you can probably get away without using that since you are avoiding js.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use your idea, and maybe applying style direct to the box that is supposed to be open might work.

Comment: I tried several things but it seems that not works. I'll just put a reference for the place the person is. Thanks!